# Docker build isn't sharing MAC's network interfaces

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am simply trying to pull down a docker container and pass the host's network interfaces directly to the container. I have a very simple docker setup situation. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    app:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
          network: host
        command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

However, when I get inside of the docker container, its network interfaces are the default ones that come with the container -- just eth0 and loopback, although I have about 10 interfaces on my host, including a tunnel interface.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that the host networking mode doesn't work on Docker for Mac, so that explains it.